# SQL Server dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table in our datawarehouse DB with 6 billion rows which is basically all the transactions that has happened in several years. This has ColumnStore Index which includes all columns and there are no other indexes. There is a UI where the user will provide multiple search criteria (say based on date/amount/paymentype) etc and I have to query this table and return TOP 1000 result.

I have already gone through various post that suggested below.

1. Use a variable with various if conditions and build the sql dynamically. Use sp_ExecuteSQL - The SQL gets very messy with all these logic
2. Use `Coalesce`, `IsNull` OR `CASE` in `WHERE` clause - This looks neat but terribly slow. For example `WHERE Total = 10` takes (1 second) whereas `Total = Coalesce(@Total, Total)` takes several minutes to run. Same delay with `IsNull` and `CASE`

I just wanted to confirm if there are no other way to do dynamic SQL except for the above 2 approaches? Appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: This is commonly known as a "catch-all" query. They are very common for searches and other uses. Here is a great article on the topic which discusses several options for making these work fast. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Another Gail Shaw article on the topic... https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is commonly referred to as a "catch all query"... There are several ways to approach this.

1) Dynamic SQL is a valid option but may be over kill.
2) Can work, just make sure you add OPTION(RECOMPILE) and the end of your query.

The reason you went from 1 second to several mins is because you went from an index seek to an index scan... OPTION(recompile) will allow the optimizer to choose a seek plan.

Comment: Adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) made the different to dynamic WHERE with ((@Total IS NULL) OR (Total=@Total)). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may prove more efficient.

```
WHERE 
    ((@Total IS NULL) OR (Total=@Total))
    AND
    ((@Param2 IS NULL) OR (Field2=@Parem2))
```

Comment: "WHERE Total = @Total" takes 1 second where as "WHERE ((@Total IS NULL) OR (Total=@Total))" takes 8 seconds

Comment: Most likely for the same reason your original query was slow .... parameter sniffing. In this case whatever code gets complied and cached first will be the fastest

Comment: Yes, OPTION(RECOMPILE) will almost certainly get around the abnormal delays in your search procedure.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is like this.

```
where Field1 = @aMandatoryParameter
and (Field2 = @optionalPameter or @inputPameter is null)
```